# Git: Trying to track which remote branches introduced files

Tags: git

In a current project, we maintain multiple remote branches. For example:

```
[me@server]$ git branch -a
  master
* featureX
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/featureX
  remotes/origin/featureY
```

Now let's say the following events happen:

1. I add "myfile.php" to featureX and push it up to remotes/origin/featureX
2. Feature X is finished, and so I merge it back into master.
3. We start up a new project called Feature Z (remotes/origin/featureZ) that is a new branch coming off of master, so it has myfile.php in it.
4. A developer on Feature Z makes changes to that file and commits it, but doesn't merge it back yet.

At this point, is it possible to show a log of myfile.php that shows the remote branches where the file was actively changed or introduced? For example:

```
myfile.php Changelog:
2014-06-05 :: DeveloperZ  :: remotes/origin/featureZ  (updated)
2014-06-04 :: DeveloperMe :: remotes/origin/master    (merged)
2014-06-03 :: DeveloperMe :: remotes/origin/featureX  (created)
```

I've been trying to read similar requests and I'm getting a little lost. It sounds like fast-forwarding (which is used in our projects) causes some problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit:*
@Cupcake prompted me for a more complete answer, one that deals with the fast-forwards<sup>1</sup> that you mentioned.

A pretty good overall survey of the history of a file is

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline \2
        --branches \
        --simplify-by-decoration -- path/to/file
```

---

To find the introducing commit for content,
 `git blame file`

To find the oldest commit introducing a path:

> `git log --oneline --`*`file`*`| tail -n1`

To find the merge history from a commit to your current checkout, regardless of whether you're still tracking that branch:
 `git log --ancestry-path --merges --oneline commit..@` but that will miss fast-forwards.  You could add `--simplify-by-decoration` to see any still-active refs in there.

---

... depending on how your project uses tags, some of those may produce enough noise to be annoying. You can drop single-tag-only commits with this little monstrosity:

```
# eliminate single-tag-commit clutter from the above output:

git log --color=always --rest-of-args \
| grep -v '([^:,]*tag:[^,]*)' \
| less -r
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Fast-forwards shine at building clean publishable branches, but as you've discovered not so much at integrating pulls of those branches.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> I've found `git alias lgdo '!git log --graph --decorate --oneline ${@---all}'` very useful.</sup>

Comment: As pointed out by [bames53's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064800/456814), you would actually want to use the `git branch --remotes --contains <commit>` command to find which ***remote branch*** introduced a change.

Comment: Except that "Commit 'X' will be listed as being in the branches master, featureX and featureZ.", and "The commit structure makes it obvious that the file was introduced in featureX." mean only that the command he gives won't actually tell you where that commit comes from, to do that you have to examine the ancestry path from that commit to `HEAD` aka `@`.  Examining that ancestry path will tell you the entire history of the branches it was merged from.  `git branch --contains` is a last resort to fall back on here, to use anything available when fast-forwards hide ancestry, not a first resort.

Comment: @Cupcake Actually, even then `branch --contains` isn't the right command.  `git log --oneline --ancestry-path --decorate --simplify-by-decoration <commit>..@` is.  It gets a more complete answer in a single command.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired and I forgot about the fact that a commit `X` can show up as being contained by multiple remote branches.

Comment: @Cupcake np, two heads better because stuff like this, today you, tomorrow me (not for the first time) ...  plus, you did point out he's dealing with fast-forwards, so today me, too, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly find the commit that introduces the file, but there's no permanent relationship between commits and branches. If you leave the feature branch alone then You can figure out the relationship:

```
                                                            master
*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*
    \               /               \               /
     X---*---*---*--                 *---*---*---*--
                 featureX                         featureZ
```

Say commit 'X' introduces the file in question. Commit 'X' will be listed as being in the branches master, featureX and featureZ. The commit structure makes it obvious that the file was introduced in featureX. You could probably write a script to figure out which of the branches commit 'X' is in is the 'closest'.

If you ever delete the branch then you'll still be able to see the feature branch commit structure related to it, but there won't be any indication in git as to what the feature branch was. Presumably commit messages or source code comments will tell you what the feature being worked on was.

---

To figure this out using `git branch --contains` you would do the following:

```
> git branch --contains X
master
featureZ
featureX
> git branch --contains master
master
> git branch --contains featureZ
master
featureZ
> git branch --contains featureX
master
featureZ
featureX
```

Since the branch featureX is contained by the same set of branches as the commit X is, that's the feature branch that introduced X.

Comment: I think that's the key there - we WOULD leave the remote branch alone, even after merging in the changes. I've been able to figure out how to see the commits for a file using git log, but now I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to associate a commit to a branch as long as that remote branch stays alive.

Comment: You can query what branches contain the commit: `git branch --contains <sha1>` but that won't be limited to just the feature branch you want. Viewing the repo history in gitk will let you figure it out by browsing commits. You can also use `git branch --contains` to figure out which branches contain the others.